# What is better in this case, document.createElement or document.write?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Ok, so I'm making an html5 canvas/javascript game. I'm playing around with the idea of making it available to anyone who wants to put the game on their own website, via one little script snippet that links to an external js file.

Inside the external js file, the whole entire game is included, all I need is to find the best way to create a canvas tag via javascript code.

**The external js link:**

```
<script src="http://host.com/game.js"></script>
```

**Here is the single line of canvas code that I need to insert into the document:**

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="display:block;margin:0px auto;" width="600" height="550">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas element.</canvas>
```

**1. My first option would be to use..**

```
document.write('<canvas id="canvas" style="display:block;margin:0px auto;" width="600" height="550">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas element.</canvas>');
```

However, document.write is frowned upon from what I understand.

**2. My next option is to use..**

```
document.createElement(canvas);
document.setAttribute(.....);
document.appendChild(....);
```

However, this option means I must include a div or some element with the external js link, so that I can append the canvas to it.

**3. My last known option is to use..**

```
document.getElementById('divWrapper').innerHTML('my canvas code');
```

However, this option also means I must include a div with the external js link, so that I can find the id of the div, and write inside it via innerHTML.

**Last tip:** People will be able to copy the external js link and paste it on their own website in the body, (it will not be in the head), and if my option requires a div tag with the script link, that is fine. I'm going for the least amount of characters that the person has to copy/paste.

**So what option would you recommend? Is there another better way that I didn't mention?**

Comment: If `document.write` is called when the HTML is parsed, then it's fine.

Comment: You mean by including the external js link in the body, it is parsing it as the html page is loaded, which would be fine right?

Comment: Yes..... would even be fine in the head (but would not make sense there (`canvas` element in the `head`)). But you should not call that method  *after* the DOM is parsed, otherwise you overwrite the content.

Comment: Yeah, i agree. And could I not just call document.write() anywhere in the js file? It doesn't have to go in a function to be called does it?

Comment: Should not matter. But I rarely use `document.write`, so my suggestion here would be: Just try it :)

Comment: I have used it before when I made a website clock widget thing. I'm just searching for the best way to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I should probably make this an answer.</sub>

If [`document.write` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.write) is called when the HTML is parsed (which seems to be the case), then it's perfectly fine to use it.

I would not write longer HTML code with it, but one line of HTML is ok.

**Advantages of `document.write`:** (in this case)

Easier for the user to add to his page (just copy and past).

**Advantages of `innerHTML`:**

You could provide the user the option to specify the id of the element to append the canvase to. This increases the flexibility for the user, but requires an additional step.

Comment: Yeah, i agree. I might use it, but innerHTML seems to be more of a fool proof solution, less chances of error.

Answer (score 3):

`document.write` is deprecated, don't use it.
I'd use innerHTML. Adding one div is totally fine and it gives the people, who insert the game, more control where to insert it.

Comment: Yeah, innerHTML seemed to me like the best way as well.

Comment: Who says it is deprecated? There are situations where it is perfectly fine to use it. Unfortunately some (I would assume, new) JavaScript developers use it in the wrong context.

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` is not a good idea as it only works when called before the document is completely loaded.

A good idea is to use DOM as it is more x-browser.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute(...);
document.getElementById(...).appendChild(canvas);
```

Comment: If i used it, it would be called before the document has finished loading though because the external js link is in the body.. in this case it would be fine then? Right?

Comment: @Jake It is possible to use `document.write` if you are sure it will always be executed during the DOM composition. Another possible problem of using this resource is that the printed string will be placed right after the `script` element not in a specific position.

Answer (score -1):

PPK had run a test on innerhtml vs dom and here is his finding, http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html, all votes/praises for innerHTML