# Which is better for SCRIPT - document.write VS document.createElement

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have seen cases where people call .js scripts dynamically, like:

```
async document.write(\'<script async src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"><\/script>\');
```

and

```
(function(){
  var newscript = document.createElement("script"); newscript.async = true;
      newscript.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js";
  (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(newscript);
})();
```

What are drawbacks of each of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is better in this case, document.createElement or document.write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929594/what-is-better-in-this-case-document-createelement-or-document-write)

Comment: An async `document.write` call most likely doesn't do what is intended ...

Comment: @JeremyThille No, that doesnt answer because my question (last sentence) is different.